# Java 8 streams , filter out Array and get count, then iterate through array up to previous Count variable

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I have an array, for example

```
List<Integer> myArray = Arrays.asList(4, 13, 10, 21, 20);
```

I want to get a count of total **even** nums in this array, so I used something like this:

```
int evenCount = (int)myArray.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).count();
```

So count should be **3** in this case, but I wanted to have some *clean concise* code and maybe chain together some more methods to iterate through the same array but *up to this* **count** value that I just computed, then calculate the number of **odd** numbers below this boundary line, something like:

```
return IntStream.range(0, evenCount-1).filter(i -> i % 2 !=0).count();
```

Is there a better way to do this in 1 line? I feel like I am redundantly looping 2 times, but could solve the problem in the first loop (iteration)...

Comment: If you need to count all the even numbers and use that count as an index, you would have to iterate twice. Or else you would need to maintain a complex indexing while you traverse the first time which could depict, each even numbers index and the count of odd values found before it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in this case you can

```
    Map<Boolean, Long> result = List.of(4, 13, 10, 21, 20).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e % 2 == 0, Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println("result = " + result); // result = {false=2, true=3}
```